# How do I write a handle-analog for mapM_ putStrLn (as in hPutStrLn -analog- putStrLn)?

Tags: haskell, types, io, file-handling

If we let `string_one = "Apple computer Bitcoin"` then the function chain `mapM_ putStrLn (sort (words string_one))` will output the following column to the screen:

```
Apple
Bitcoin
computer
```

I need a function that will output in the same manner to an output handle, i.e., each word to its own line in an output.txt file. To the best of my ability am I managing the pure/action nuances, but haven't solved this yet...

The type declaration for `mapM_ putStrLn :: [String] -> IO ()` so I assume something like `hMapm_putStrLn :: Handle -> [String] -> IO ()` is reasonable for this purpose, but am not sure how to write the function definition. The final expression that I would like to be able to use should look something like:

```
hMapm_putStrLn outh (sort (words string_one))
```

Comment: How about [`hPutStrLn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hPutStrLn)? Then you have `mapM_ (hPutStrLn outh) (sort (words string_one))`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks! If you don't mind, can you explain (briefly) why this works?

Comment: Remember that functions in Haskell are curried, so `hPutStrLn outh :: String -> IO ()`. Does that help?

Comment: It does. I was (more so) unsure about the effect moving `mapM_` to the head-position would have on the output. Seeing its type declaration now, I'm beginning to have a better understanding. Thanks, Alec!